# Surly mood to describe someone's personality

Tags: vocabulary

How do you use "surly" to describe someone's personality?
Can you say "he has a surly mood"?
Thanks!

Comment: Voting to close as answers will be readily apparent on quite simple research. @Gemma If you can tell us more about your question, why you have the question, and what information you have found about it, this is a better question. First, you should search for the word online and in a few dictionaries and see if you still have a question.

Comment: Include an online search for "in a surly mood" (include the quotes in your search). If you still have a question after looking a bit, please edit your question and we would love to try to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, *Surly* is an adjective which means to *be bad-tempered and unfriendly*. This word can be used to describe a person's Mood, or his Nature in general.

See this:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surly (3rd point)